# Expo doesn't show Logs

Tags: react-native, expo

When I run my react-native app I can't see my logs.
The device where I started it doesn't even show up in the list. I tested it with iOS, android and an simulator. Any suggestions?

I use the following expo versions:

"expo": "^40.0.0",

"expo-cli": "3.28.6",

[image: expo]

Comment: Your logs are in the console you're running expo on

Comment: No, the logs don't show anywhere. Also there usually should appear an extra item in the expo list where I can see the logs. Neither of the two cases happen for me

Comment: Maybe you or another library has overridden the console.log function create a new project and see if console.log works there

Comment: indeed! For any one having the same problem, it was: @react-native-community/slider

Comment: Glad I helped I also posted it as an answer feel free to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override console functions like console.log and that can completely change the way they work, it can also intend to do nothing and just disable the log in these cases just remove the libraries you installed recently or restore your project to the point the console worked then find the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was running the app on an emulator on my local machine.
What solved it for me was changing the connection setting from LAN to LOCAL.
Either change it through the expo developer tools or just run `expo start --localhost` instead of `expo start`

Answer (score 0):

Change a device name to English!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).